# ¿Porqué, no sale del ciclo While al usar OR y distinto (!=) ? C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Ayuda, el programa no reconoce el dato Ingresado y sigue repitiendo el ciclo:

```
intro#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int contM=0,contJ=0,contP=0,contN=0;
char opcion;
do{
    cout<<" Candidatos:  \n"
        <<" M-Maria \n"
        <<" J-Juan \n"
        <<" P-Pedro \n"
        <<" S-Salir \n\t";
    cin>>opcion;
        switch (opcion){
            case 'm':
            case 'M':
                contM++;
                break;
            case 'j':
            case 'J':
                contJ++;
                break;
            case 'p':
            case 'P':
                contP++;
            default : contN++;
            break;          
        }
}while (opcion !='s')||( opcion!='S');
cout<<"\n";
cout<<" Resultados Maria: "<<contM;
cout<<"\n";
cout<<" Resultados Juan: "<<contJ;
cout<<"\n";
cout<<" Resultados Pedro: "<<contP;
cout<<"\n";
cout<<" Resultados Votos Nulos: "<<contN;
}
```

Comment: podrias agregar tu codigo completo

Comment: deberías leer algo de lógica proposicional, los `if` las manipulan bastante

Comment: Te recomiendo, de cara a un futuro, que formatees tu código a la hora de publicarlo en SOes. Principalmente, porque eso nos ayuda a nosotros a leerlo, y a ti, a aprender a escribir mejor tu código.
Así localizaremos tu error con más rapidez, y al mismo tiempo, te indicaríamos más detalles de tu código que no indicas (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Tal como no indicar cuando haces un `fall through` como haces en esos `case`s, no usar el `using namespace std;`, o declarar main sin argumentos y sin especificar qué argumentos de entrada tiene `int main (void)`, `int main(int argc, const char **argv)`, `int main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)`, entre otros. El espaciado también es importante, y te habrás fijado que los tabuladores no son muy bien aceptados por el sistema, así que usar espacios será una idea para identar tu código. Todo sea para que podamos leerlo mejor y ayudarte a mejorar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tu condicion esta mal.  Supongamos que el usuario ingresa `S`, entonces la condicion `opcion != 's'` es verdadera.  Al usar el comparador `OR`, toda la condicion se hace verdadera.  Lo que necesitas es usar `AND` en lugar de `OR` asi:

```
do{
cout<<" Candidatos:  \n"
    <<" M-Maria \n"
    <<" J-Juan \n"
    <<" P-Pedro \n"
    <<" S-Salir \n\t";
cin>>opcion;
    switch (opcion){
        case 'm':
        case 'M':
            contM++;
            break;
        case 'j':
        case 'J':
            contJ++;
            break;
        case 'p':
        case 'P':
            contP++;
        default : contN++;
        break;          
    }
}while ((opcion !='s')&&( opcion!='S'));
```

Comment: Gracias, esta es la respuesta.

Comment: De nada @Dave  Saludos

Answer (score 0):

¿Podrías probar a añadir unos paréntesis en la condición del while?

```
do {
  // ...
} while((opcion != 's') && (opcion != 'S'));
```

Comment: Lo Mismo no funciona